# How to avoid snoring?

Tags: sleep

If someone is suffering from snoring for around 5 years, are there some remedies to avoid or control snoring? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Health SE! I edited your post a little to fix readability and it being on-topic. If you disagree with it please feel free to go into the edit history and rollback. Thank You :)

Comment: Sleep position can  help.  See http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/582/does-sleeping-position-affect-health/1702#1702

Answer (score 6):

### Remedies to control snoring:

- Pillows. There is a pillow called the [SONA pillow](http://www.snore.net/review-sona-pillow/) its FDA approved and is [proven to work.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15611895)

  > The study was performed to determine the ability of a new inclined
  >   pillow to treat snoring and obstructive sleep apnea syndrome. The SONA
  >   Pillow is a triangular pillow with space to place your arm under the
  >   head while sleeping on the side.

From the [WebMD article "7 Easy Fixes for Snoring"](http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/features/easy-snoring-remedies):

- Beware sprays and pills. They can not be all they said they would be or not be properly researched to be safe or work.

  > Use caution before you self-treat with over-the-counter sprays and
  >   pills until you've checked with your doctor, says Sudhansu
  >   Chokroverty, MD, FRCP, FACP, program director for Clinical
  >   Neurophysiology and Sleep Medicine at JFK Medical Center in Edison,
  >   N.J. "Many stop-snoring aids are marketed without scientific studies
  >   to support their claims," says Chokroverty, who is also a neuroscience
  >   professor at Seton Hall University's School of Health and Medical
  >   Sciences.
- More on pillows. Utilizing full body pillows can help. Also, don't sleep on back and elevating the head of the bed can help, but may cause neck pain. Taping tennis balls to the back of your pajamas to stop yourself from lyin on your back is said to work, as well. Another warning:

  > This may cause neck pain, however." If snoring continues regardless of
  >   the sleep position, obstructive sleep apnea may be a cause. "See a
  >   doctor in this case," Chokroverty says.
- Keeping your nasal passage ways open and eliminating allergens. Change and clean bedding and remove dust and other allergy triggers. As for nasal passage ways:

> If snoring starts in your nose, keeping nasal passages open may help.
>   It allows air to move through slower, Slaughter says. "Imagine a
>   narrow garden hose with water running through. The narrower the hose,
>   the faster the water rushes through."
>
> Your nasal passages work similarly. If your nose is clogged or
>   narrowed due to a cold or other blockage, the fast-moving air is more
>   likely to produce snoring.

Things to do to fix this are:

- Hot showers before bed time
- Netti pots
- Nasal strips

[NLM.NIH.GOV](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/snoring.html) states simply.

> Lose weight if you are overweight. It may help, but thin people can
>   snore, too. Cut down or avoid alcohol and other sedatives at bedtime
>   Don't sleep flat on your back

Those can be included with some lifestyles changes mentioned by [Mayo Clinic:](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/snoring/basics/lifestyle-home-remedies/con-20031874)

- Quit smoking
- Get enough sleep
- Raise head of bed about 4 inches

[Alternative treatments](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/snoring/basics/alternative-medicine/con-20031874) mentioned are playing certain musical instruments and singing which can improve muscle control and train muscles of the upper airway.

Seeking a doctors care is very important as snoring can be a sign of [sleep apnea](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/sleepapnea.html) which can be life threatening. The [cause of snoring](http://www.britishsnoring.co.uk/why_do_i_snore/introduction_to_causes_snoring.php) is important and can change treatment. Also, of note is that [snoring can not be cured, only controlled.](http://www.britishsnoring.co.uk/cure_for_snoring.php)

By remedies I assumed you meant things other than [surgery, implants, CPAP and Radiofrequency tissue ablation.](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/snoring/basics/treatment/con-20031874)