# Sleep issues when sleeping on back

Tags: sleep, stress, back, position, recumbent-lying-down

I've always liked to sleep over my tummy. Now i'm 24 and recently noticed whenever i try to sleep properly on my back at night i feel very stressed the next day, partial sleeps, rolling on bed(even upto 180 degrees). Is this a proper sleep? And why am i rolling on bed at night when sleeping on back?

Comment: See [this question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/582/does-sleeping-position-affect-health). *Note:* not marking it as duplicate, the other question just has some useful information for you!

Comment: @Narusan thank you, that was helpful. Now i know what to look for :)

Comment: The top answer on that post is critical for you to look into, OSA, since you have multiple symptoms that should prompt you to see a doctor about it. It might be still happening in other positions, but milder and less noticeable.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I'm very silent when sleeping on tummy or sleeping sideways. No snoring and the mouth stays closed. This has nothing to do with sinus issues right(i don't have any right now)? I'll consult a doctor soon, thanks...

Comment: Sleep apnea isn't always manifested as just snoring. OCA can be mixed with central sleep apnea, etc.  I'm glad you'll go see your doctor for guidance.

Comment: @DoctorWhom I consulted doctor, explained the problems. He told me there's nothing to worry about. I have some dust allergy issues and the sleep issues may be due to blocked nostrils, phlegm in sinus etc. He prescribed some meds, now i'm fine. Mostly quiet and silent at night :D

Comment: Wonderful, glad you got to the bottom of it!  That's why an individual evaluation is so important, there are lots of things that have to be considered when deciding what symptoms mean in an individual's situation!

Comment: Well thanks again for the advise